# Attribute error for bot on 32 bit Python 2.7.11

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to run a bot for Super Hexagon (Just for fun), but when I try to run the module in IDLE 2.7.11 (32 Bit) I get the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):\

    File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 223, in <module>

    main()

    File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 219, in main

    logic.start()

     File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line >

     183, in start

     wall_list = self.hexagon.get_walls()

     File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 
    77, in get_walls

     num_walls = self.get_num_walls()

     File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 119, in get_num_walls

     num_walls = self.memory.read(self.app_base + offset)

     File "C:\Users\Spencer\Desktop\Super-Hexagon-Bot\super_hexagon_bot.py", line 35, in read

     value = int.from_bytes(self.buffer.value, byteorder=byteorder)
    AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'from_bytes'
```

If you would like to see the code I'm trying to run it's here http://pastebin.com/X34Qxrxx

Comment: You could try to use 3to2 to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is meant for Python 3. It will not run in Python 2.